# Git: Custom editor opens blank file

Tags: git, command-line, sublimetext2, default, text-editor

I set up Sublime Text 2 as my default text editor when using Git on Mac.

In my `.bash_profile` I put `export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/sublime -w"`. Whenever I open a file in command line, it opens up as a blank file. After 2-3 attempts the file then shows information like it should.

Did I set up something incorrect?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-w`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/jackilyn/2053952) mentions:

The `-w` doesn't seem to be needed anymore; Actually adding it now inverses the way it worked.
Adding it, makes the terminal command exit before editing the file in sublime
Removing it, will properly make the sublime command to not exit until the file is closed.

> Can just use this now (with no Sublime version):

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

---

> Check to see if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`: `open ~/.zshrc`
>
> Make sure it says:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/example/other/dirs/
```

> Back in the terminal enter this to refresh the file: `source ~/.zshrc`
>
> Now you can type `sublime` to open up Sublime Text:

- `sublime .` to open the current directory or
- `sublime some-file.txt` to open the directory/file in Sublime Text.

> Now, to set Sublime Text as the default editor set the EDITOR environment variable:

```
export EDITOR='sublime'
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks so much! This little issue has been driving me crazy.